non-CSS codes with transversal logical gates
The five-qubit $[[5, 1, 3]]$ perfect code is a non-CSS code and has transversal $HS$ gate.
Do we also have examples of some other non-CSS codes that has transversal $HS$ gate? Or do we in general know some non-CSS codes with any transversal gates (excluding Pauli)?

All single qubit logical Clifford gates can be implemented by permutations followed by local Clifford operations on the $[[4,1,2]]$ code:
$$ S = \langle XY ZI, IXY Z, ZIXY, Y ZIX \rangle$$
See Genons, Double Covers, and Fault-tolerant Clifford Gates
This code is the smallest code in the family of 2D color codes with Pauli boundaries. See Section 5.2 of The boundaries and twist defects of the color code and their applications to topological quantum computation. My intuition is that for the entire code family all Clifford gates can be implemented transversally, as this is the case for color codes with color boundaries.

The $[[4, 1, 2]]$ code given here can be transformed back to a CSS code with local Clifford, so they are not really non-CSS.

What is the local Clifford? Perhaps it's easier to find for [4,1,2] color code:
$$S=\langle XXIX, YIYY, IZZZ \rangle$$
